# information about SQL joins

Tags: mysql, sql

in mySQL, is it possible to join two tables without selecting data?
for example:

```
    Patient p INNER JOIN (SELECT pat_ID FROM Visit v 
    WHERE v.date_of_visit >= '2005-01-01' 
    AND v.date_of_visit < '2066-01-01')
```

Comment: Do you mean, is that a valid SQL statement? (The answer is "no".)

Comment: by "without selecting" did you mean missing out the " ON " or " WHERE " clause to match the rows from each table?

Comment: I am just trying to do it as i have to translate this relational algebra statement (Patient (join operator) pat_id(date>=1=1=2005^ date<1=1=2006(Visit)) to SQL but exactly the same order, and you see that patient is joined without selecting anything.

Comment: Stick a `SELECT *` in front and you'll be okay. (Except I think you need to provide an alias for a subquery that is a factor in a join.) I think that's what the relational algebra statement means: the set of rows that result from the join operator and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This is no valid syntax, you must combine this with SELECT, UPDATE or DELETE statement.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a [VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) that can be queried later as though it were a simple table.  It sounds like you may just want an ordinary query, though, and are figuring out how.  I'm not familiar with that relational algebra syntax, but it appears to me you have a key field in Patient (that may be called id or pat_id depending on style), and you want to join it to a foreign key in the Visit table (which is probably called pat_id).

I think you want something close to this

```
select patient p join visit v on p.pat_id=v.pat_id
where v.date>=? and v.date<=?
```